# Open user login in lightbox

Tags: 7, users, javascript

How to create a link, which will open user login in lightbox, I have installed lightbox2 module in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or try using [Ajax Login/Register](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_register), a complete solution. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides a smooth way for the user to login, register and request new password via AJAX at any Drupal site.
>
> Features:
>
> - This module provides a block with 2 links (Login, Register) for the anonymous user.
> - When the user clicks on Login or register the requested form appears in a nice ajax popup.
> - The login and register forms can validate using ajax and not redirect on error.
> - On success the module redirects to the user page.
> - When user is logged in, the block provides a Welcome !username message and a link to the user page and a logout link.
> - This module integrates the thickbox plugin with the Ajax module and provides a simple, easy to use and cool login and register block.

Comment: This works perfectly! Surprisingly very few sites use it

Answer (score 1):

You can add rel="lightmodal" to any anchor and it will be opened in a lightbox.
Also I'm almost sure lightbox2 have this option (login lightbox) out of the box, check the settings form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: http://drupal.org/project/colorbox I believe it allows for this functionality out of the box. This post explains how to make a login link open in the colorbox; http://drupal.org/node/883210

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the [AJAX Login/Register](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register) module adds a block with a login button. Clicking on that button opens a popup login/register dialog.

However, I think the question was how to make **any link** open the login dialog (e.g. I have blog posts, and clicking on the post title should also open the dialog.

[This code does the trick](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/open-the-ajax-login-register-popup-when-clicking-on-post-titles) however unlike the regular block dialog, it takes 5 seconds until the popup loads. Anyone knows why?