# Open the AJAX Login/Register popup when clicking on post titles

Tags: ajax, users, javascript

The [AJAX Login/Register](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_register) module adds a block with a login button. Clicking on that button opens a nice popup login/register dialog.

But how to make the login dialog open when clicking on post titles?

I tried to add a block with this code:

```
<a href='ajax_register/login/nojs' 
   classes='ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-ctools-ajax-register-style' 
   rel='nofollow'>
     My Post Title
</a>
```

However it doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a typographic error. Use "`class=...`" instead of "`classes=...`"

Comment: Yes, it works... :)